# Non-triviality of class type due to presence of default member initializer(s)

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

As one may expect, the use of default member initializers for non-static data members makes a class non-trivial:

```
// Well-formed according to both GCC and Clang (-std=c++17).
#include <type_traits>

struct Trivial { int a; int b; };
struct NotTrivial { int a; int b{0}; };

static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<Trivial>, "");
static_assert(!std::is_trivial_v<NotTrivial>, "");

int main() {}
```

What passage of the (C++17) standard governs that `NotTrivial` is a non-trivial class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

[[class]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#6) governs what is a *trivial class* [extract]:

> [...] A *trivial class* is a class that is trivially copyable and has one or more default constructors, all of which are either trivial or deleted and at least one of which is not deleted. [...]

Let's denote the *trivial class* requirements as follows:

- **(A)** the class is trivially copyable, and
- **(B)** all the default constructors of the class are either trivial or deleted, and
- **(C)** the class has at least one non-deleted default constructor.

As will be shown below, `NonTrivial` fulfills requirements **(A)** and **(C)**, but fails requirement **(B)**, and is thus not trivial.

---

#### Requirement (A): trivially copyable [fulfilled]

Requirement **(A)** is governed by [[class]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#6):

> A *trivially copyable class* is a class:
>
> - *(6.1)* where each copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator ([class.copy],
>   [over.ass]) is either deleted or trivial,
> - *(6.2)* that has at least one non-deleted copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator,
>   and
> - *(6.3)* that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor.

where the first sub-requirement *(6.1)* covering *triviality* of constructors and assignment operators is governed by [[class.copy.ctor]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.ctor#11) and [[class.copy.assign]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.assign#9), respectively:

> **[class.copy.ctor]/11**
>
> A copy/move constructor for class `X` is trivial if it is not
> user-provided and if:
>
> - *(11.1)* class `X` has no virtual functions and no virtual base classes, and
> - *(11.2)* the constructor selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is trivial, and
> - *(11.3)* for each non-static data member of `X` that is of class type (or array thereof), the constructor selected to copy/move that member
>   is trivial;
>
> otherwise the copy/move constructor is *non-trivial*.
>
> **[class.copy.assign]/9**
>
> A copy/move assignment operator for class `X` is trivial if it is not
> user-provided and if:
>
> - *(9.1)* class `X` has no virtual functions and no virtual base classes, and
> - *(9.2)* the assignment operator selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is trivial, and
> - *(9.3)* for each non-static data member of `X` that is of class type (or array thereof), the assignment operator selected to copy/move that
>   member is trivial;
>
> otherwise the copy/move assignment operator is *non-trivial*.

which are all fulfilled by `NonTrivial`.

The second sub-requirement *(6.2)* covering *existence* of constructors and assignment operators, **when restricted to implicitly declared special functions** (as is the case for this example), is governed by [[class.copy.ctor]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.ctor#6) and [[class.copy.assign]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.assign#2), respectively:

> **[class.copy.ctor]/6**
>
> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy
> constructor, a non-explicit one is declared *implicitly*. If the class
> definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator,
> the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted;
> otherwise, it is defined as defaulted. [...]
>
> **[class.copy.assign]/2**
>
> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment
> operator, one is declared *implicitly*. If the class definition
> declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the
> implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted;
> otherwise, it is defined as defaulted. [...]

Thus, a copy constructor and copy assignment operator will be implicitly declared for `NonTrivial`. It follows from [[class.copy.ctor]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.ctor#8) and [[class.copy.assign]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.assign#4) 4that the same holds for for the move constructor and move assignment operator, respectively. Thus, `NonTrivial` fulfills the sub-requirement *(6.2)*.

The third sub-requirement *(6.3)* is governed by [[class.dtor]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.dtor#6):

> A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> - (6.1) the destructor is not virtual,
> - (6.2) all of the direct base classes of its class have trivial destructors, and
> - (6.3) for all of the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial
>   destructor.
>
> Otherwise, the destructor is *non-trivial*.

which is fulfilled by `NonTrivial`, and thus requirement **(A)** holds for `NonTrivial`.

---

#### Requirement (B): trivial or deleted default constructors [NOT fulfilled]

As governed by [[class.ctor]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#4) [extract]:

> [...] If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted ([dcl.fct.def]).

a default constructor will be implicitly declared for the `NonTrivial` class. However, as governed by [[class.ctor]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#6), particularly [[class.ctor]/6.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#6.2), this implicitly declared default constructor **is not trivial**:

> A default constructor is *trivial* if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> - [...]
> - *(6.2)* no non-static data member of its class has a default member initializer ([class.mem]), and [...]

And thus the `NonTrivial` class fails the requirement **(B)**, and is thus not trivial.

We may note that the clause [class.ctor]/6.2 originated from the original proposal for non-static data member initializers, [N2628](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2628.html), which proposed adding

> no non-static data member of its class has an *assignment-initializer*, and

as an additional triviality requirement to [class.ctor].

---

#### Requirement (C): existence of a default constructor [fulfilled]

For completeness, we may note that the `NonTrivial` class fulfills requirement **(C)**, as per [[class.ctor]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#4) (quoted to in the section above).